# Google Assistant not showing messages

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-assistant

[image]

The image above shows the problem. I hear the voice, but no text shows up showing the response. This goes for any input: I hear the voice, but what the assistant says doesn't show up on the screen as text. It used to in earlier versions. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem running 7.0 android on the Samsung Galaxy s7 edge. I clicked on settings then  applications found the Google app clicked on it then I cleared all data and that erased all of the updates taking it back to the stock installed version from their I  updated the app restarted my phone and  my Google assistant works fine .hope this helps